# Star rating with two GET

Tags: php, javascript, html, rating

I´ve got a star image as `<img>`. This image has a javascript function, that is called on click. The javascript method is called `addRating(var data)`. `data` is the rating number(1-10).

Now in the javascript function, I want to call the php `rate_recipe` that wants two GET, one for the rating and one for the recipe_id.

How can I "pass" two things to the php? Can I just add two  `$_GET` ?

**EDIT1**:
this is the code of the php:

```
            include 'db_connect.php';
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
    $rate = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['rate']);
    $exist = 0;
    $recipes_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['recipes_id']);
```

.. so now, how can I call it in `addRating(var data)`?
I want to stay at the same page, just want to do the rate.

Comment: show us the code of your javascript and php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call a PHP function via JavaScript, you'll need to do so via AJAX. If you're using plain JavaScript, you'll use the XMLHttpRequest object:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest

Or if you're using jQuery (recommended):

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Now since you'll be collecting data, the proper convention is to `post` the data. Here's an example of how to do it with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: "rating=10&id=5997"
}).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Where `some.php` is the location of your PHP script.

Comment: ok thanks, I changed the whole thing to `POST`. What can I do if this does not work? I tried to alert msg after this but nothing happened

Comment: Are you using the sample code I provided? Have you included jQuery? In your PHP, change all `$_GET`'s to `$_POST`s.

Comment: yes, I used your code, changed the variables to mine. I also changed all the `$_GET` s. And yes, I´ve included jQuery! Heres the code: 


`function addRating(data1)
{
alert(data1);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/rate_recipe.php",
    data: "rate=data1&recipes_id=5"
}).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );

});
 alert('123');
}`

Comment: That seems fine to me. So the `alert` never happens? Try `echo`ing something out in your PHP script. The `msg` parameter in the done function is the text content of whatever is `printed` in your PHP file, though it should not be necessary to print anything out.

Comment: I tried to `echo` something but there is still no alert for `msg`. the `alert('123')` after it works fine!

Comment: Can you post a link to the page in question? I might be able to help more if I can see what's actually going on.

Comment: The link is `http://vm18.htl-leonding.ac.at/recipe_search.php?id=61`. Now I found out that in firefox, I get a alert for msg, not in Chrome. What can I do??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9408/discussion-between-wanovak-and-user896692)

Answer (score 0):

Like this: `index.php?recipe_id=123&rating=5`

You'll get it in php with
`$_GET['recipe_id']`
and
`$_GET['rating']`